Is possible to automatically Set Dropdown Value Based on URL Parameter in FormCraft Form on WordPress?
I am working with a FormCraft form on a WordPress site and trying to automatically set the value of a Select2 dropdown based on a URL parameter. I have been struggling to get it to work despite multiple attempts with various JavaScript approaches. Here are the details and what I've tried:
Objective: I want to automatically select the "Ouvidoria" option in a dropdown within a FormCraft form when the form is accessed via a URL with a specific parameter (e.g., ?assunto=Ouvidoria).
Environment:

WordPress site with the FormCraft plugin.
The dropdown is enhanced by the Select2 plugin.
The form is incorporated into the page using a shortcode like [fc id='1'][/fc].
The dropdown field specifically has the ID field13 within the form.

Attempts:
Initial JavaScript Attempt:
Tried using a simple document.ready function combined with setTimeout to ensure the Select2 is fully loaded. I attempted to select the dropdown using its specific class .fc-form .form-element-field13 select and apply the value from the URL parameter.
Issue: The script either runs too early before the form is fully initialized or doesn't select the correct field due to dynamic rendering by FormCraft and Select2.
Using Interval to Check Element Existence:
Set up an interval to check every 100ms if the dropdown is available in the DOM before applying the value.
Issue: This approach didn't consistently work, possibly due to incorrect targeting of the DOM element or conflicts with how FormCraft dynamically loads content.
Select2 Trigger Method:
Used selectField.val(assunto).trigger('change.select2') to programmatically set the dropdown value.
Issue: No change is observed in the dropdown; it seems like the Select2 isn't recognizing the change or the script isn't targeting the right element.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var assunto = urlParams.get('assunto');
    setTimeout(function() {
        var selectField = $(".fc-form .form-element-field13 select");
        if (selectField.length) {
            selectField.val(assunto).trigger('change.select2');
            console.log('Dropdown set to:', assunto);
        }
    }, 1000);
});


Questions:
How can I ensure the script correctly targets and modifies the Select2 dropdown once it is fully initialized in a FormCraft form?
Is there a more reliable method to wait for the dynamic elements of FormCraft and Select2 to be ready before executing JavaScript?
Any insights or alternative approaches to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Can you edit your question to provide an example of one of the rendered forms so we can see the structure?

For a select 2 field, just use instead selectField.val(assunto).change(); in your code… It will work.
